# C# double type formatting without decimal point and 2 digits

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I need to format a double as a string with 15 chars, padded left with zeros (0).
  The string must contain the 2 digits but not the decimal point even thousand separator.

I did it using the below code, but I wonder if there is a better way to do using only format string.

```cs
double value = 15.85;
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string s = (value).ToString("F2", info).Replace(".", string.Empty).PadLeft(15, "0"[0]);
//will output 000000000001585
```

Comment: Off topic tip: to use a literal character, use single quotes: `.PadLeft(15, '0')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a way to show fractional digits without the decimal point *purely* with a format string, but there's a simpler way to remove the decimal point than string replacement/padding - just multiply the value by 100:

```
(value*100).ToString("000000000000000");
```

Comment: Simple and usefull. This solve even the culture problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
double value = 15.85;

string s1 = String.Format("{0:000000000000000}", value); // 000000000000015
string s2 = String.Format("{0:0000.00}", value);         // 0015.85
```

Comment: Neither of those gives the output the OP asks for (`000000000001585`).

Comment: @DStanley Ah, interpreted it as though he didn't want anything beyond the decimal point. Could just do `String.Format("{0:000000000000000}", value * 100);`.

Comment: @LuizVaz I'm confused then, because you get a different output with this approach.

Comment: @DStanley you came with the solution, but this one is more beautiful. Magnus comment fix the problem.